# How can I access ANDROID_ID in library code?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I want to access the value of [Settings#ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) in a library code.

I found that [Secure#getString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#getString(android.content.ContentResolver, java.lang.String)) requires an `ContentResolver`.

How can I access the value without a `ContentResolver` or is there any global value for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `ANDROID_ID` without a `ContentResolver`. The `ANDROID_ID` is stored in a database which is handled by the System.

To ensure that not anyone can access any data of the database, Android uses Content Providers. These are also used by the `ContentResolver`.

So you can only access these values with a Content Provider.

I guess you have to transfer a `ContentResolver` to you library functions.